# Multi-component routing by nested routing, react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to use nested routing but it doesn't show the page I want and instead, it shows "not found" page. I am using react-router-dom version 6. On the App page, there is a NavBar and all routes. I want to go to the admin/users route but it doesn't seem to find it and redirects to the "not available" page.
Child routes are in another component.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products sortBy="newest" />} />
            <Route path="/posts/:year?/:month?" element={<Posts />} />
            <Route path="/message" element={<Navigate replace to="/posts" />} />
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import SideBar from "./sidebar";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./users";
import Posts from "./posts";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
      <SideBar />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/admin/users" element={<Users />} />
        <Route path="/admin/posts" element={<Posts />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```